# Обработка изображения. Определение яркости.

Tags: java, android, изображения

Как определить яркость изображения? (Как я предполагаю, среднее значение Brightness, если цвета изображения из RGB в HSV перевести)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В модели RGB, значение каждого канала задает интенсивность (яркость) по каналу, но к несчастью глаз так устроен, что при одинаковой интенсивности желтый кажется более ярким чем синий. Чтобы учесть это обстоятельство придумано туча формул:

```
1) Яркость1 = 0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B
2) Яркость2 = sqrt(0.299*R^2 + 0.587*G^2 + 0.114*B^2)
3) Яркость3 = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
4) И.т.д.
```

Под каждой из формул лежит суровая математика/опыт и физиология, погуглите и обрящете.

Comment: Надо выбрать одну из этих формул и вычислить среднюю яркость всех пикселей?

Comment: Да, именно. Правда, есть особые теоретики, которые полагают, что весовой вклад в общую яркость пикселей по центру изображения должен быть чуть больше, чем пикселей по краям. Но я думаю, что это уже слишком.

Comment: К тому же, наверняка, чувствительность к яркости по цветам и по шкале интенсивности неравномерна и, самое страшное, индивидуальна. Поэтому пользователю следует сначала пройти субъективные калибровочные тесты на его устройстве, и тогда по полученным данным ранжировать изображения персонально для него : )